# Splitting a large XML file based on N occurrences of a given element

Tags: xml, perl

I'm looking to split a ~300MB XML file into separate files based on N occurrences of a given element.

My source XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmlcore:Sensor
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd"
        xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1">
  <paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>      
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name1</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number1</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name2</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number2</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name3</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number3</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name4</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number4</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
</pmlcore:Sensor>
```

If my input file is as above, then I would like to split this into separate files based on every 10 occurrences of the `pmlcore:Observation` element.

For testing purposes, say with my input XML as above, I would like to see files split for every 2 occurrences of the `pmlcore:Observation` element (with the first two lines of the input file—XML prolog and `paraID:ID`—inserted into each split file).

My XML then would be split into two files:

#### Name1.txt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmlcore:Sensor
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd"
        xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1">
  <paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>      
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name1</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number1</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name2</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number2</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
</pmlcore:Sensor>
```

#### Name2.txt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmlcore:Sensor
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd"
        xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1">
  <paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>      
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name3</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number3</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name4</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number4</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
</pmlcore:Sensor>
```

I've been able to do this with awk but the process has been painfully slow. I'd like to know if there's a simple but effective way to accomplish this via a Perl script (perhaps using
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig)
).

Comment: Your XML is not well formed: the ID opening and closing tags have different namespace. There's no root node. Can you show the definitions of the namespaces?

Comment: @choroba, I've updated the XML. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't help you unless we get a better idea of what your XML looks like. There may be only a single document element, and you have five; `<paraid:ID>1234</pmluid:ID>` has a closing tag that doesn't match the opening tag, and the various namespace prefixes aren't declared.

Comment: You need to provide the XSD file that is in your document element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader), a pull parser from libxml2:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;
use constant {
    SIZE    => 2, # 10
    PMLUID  => 'urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1',
    PMLCORE => 'urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1',
};

my $name_tally = 0;
sub output {
    my ($orig_root, $id, @observations) = @_;

    my $root = $orig_root->cloneNode;
    $root->addChild($id);
    $root->addChild($_) for @observations;
    ++$name_tally;
    open my $OUT, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', "Name$name_tally.txt" or die $!;
    print {$OUT} $root;
    print STDERR "$name_tally\n";
}

my $reader = 'XML::LibXML::Reader'->new(location => shift)
    or die;

$reader->read;
my $root = $reader->copyCurrentNode;

$reader->nextElement('ID', PMLUID) or die "No ID\n";
my $id = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);

my @observations;
while ($reader->nextElement('Observation', PMLCORE)) {
    push @observations, $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    if (@observations == SIZE) {
        output($root, $id, @observations);
        @observations = ();
    }
}
# Output the reminder if the size and total are coprime.
output($root, $id, @observations) if @observations;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this with `XML::Twig` using `purge` to keep memory footprint down.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

#the number of elements per file
my $subelt_count = 2;
#a running tally for numbering output files
my $count        = 1;
#a holding space for the current 'batch' that gets emptied each time
my @processed_elements;

#called when the parser hits a matching element, as it goes. 
sub process_xml {
   my ( $twig, $elt ) = @_;

   push( @processed_elements, $elt );

   if ( @processed_elements >= $subelt_count ) {

      #2 processed so far, start a new file
      open( my $output, ">", "file_" . $count++ . ".xml" ) or die $!;
      print {$output} $twig->sprint;
      close($output);

      #delete the elements we've already printed
      $_->delete for @processed_elements;
      @processed_elements = ();
      #Dump processed stuff from memory
      $twig -> purge;
   }
}

my $parser =
  XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers => { 'pmlcore:Observation' => \&process_xml } );
$parser->set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$parser->parsefile ( 'input_file_name.xml' );

#in case there's any trailing elements (e.g. there's not exactly a multiple of $subelt_count in the file), otherwise they'll be discarded
if ( $parser->get_xpath('//pmlcore:Observation') ) {
   $parser->print;
}
```

Note - this will work at a level of `<pmlcore:Observation>` tags - so your `<paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>`  will only be printed in one document. I can't tell if this is a special case that should be handled explicitly, but you can take a similar approach with preserving this tag too. Otherwise the first `$twig -> purge` will clear out any closed tags to saved memory which will include this one.

There's no way around that at the same time as using `purge` to save memory. If you don't `purge` you *might* still be ok, because we are deleting elements as we go.

So you can either:

- comment out the `$twig -> purge` line. (and accept that might increase memory overhead, but it might not)
- 'save' the 'paraid'

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $subelt_count = 2;
my $count        = 1;
my @processed_elements;

my $paraid; 

sub process_xml {
   my ( $twig, $elt ) = @_;

   push( @processed_elements, $elt );
   if ( my $new_paraid = $elt -> parent -> first_child('paraid:ID') ) {
      $paraid = $new_paraid;
      $paraid -> cut; 
   }
   if ( @processed_elements >= $subelt_count ) {

      #2 processed so far, start a new file
      open( my $output, ">", "file_" . $count++ . ".xml" ) or die $!;
      $paraid -> paste ( $twig -> root );
      print {$output} $twig->sprint;
      close($output);
      $_->delete for @processed_elements;
      @processed_elements = ();
      $twig -> purge;
   }
}

my $parser =
  XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers => { 'pmlcore:Observation' => \&process_xml } );
$parser->set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$parser->parsefile ( 'your_input_file.xml' );

#in case there's any trailing elements;
if ( $parser->get_xpath('//pmlcore:Observation') ) {
   $parser->print;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! The first script works, except for the issue where the paraid was inserted only on the first file. 
Running the second script results in this error:
amra1700:/home/vikkrn/xmlsplit$ ./Perlsplit2.pl
Can't call method "paste" on an undefined value at ./Perlsplit2.pl line 24.
 at ./Perlsplit2.pl line 37
 at ./Perlsplit2.pl line 37

Comment: Why `print {$output} $twig->sprint` instead of `$twig->print($output)`?

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you ask. It uses the `twig_roots` facility of the
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) module
so that the whole of the XML data is not accumulated in memory

There is a callback for `pmlcore:Observation` elements. When one of these is found. If this results in `CHUNK_SIZE` such elements then `print_chunk` is called to write a new chunk file, and remove all  `pmlcore:Observation` elements ready for adding new children

After the file is parsed, the copy is checked for `pmlcore:Observation` elements that were never written to disk. `print_chunk` is called again if any are found

Note that I have added a fifth `pmlcore:Observation` to the test data to test the case where there isn't a exact number of chunks in the block. This results in `Name3.txt` being written with just one observation point

I've also used the `autodie` pragma to avoid having to explicitly test the status of every IO operation such as `open` and `close`

***This program expects the path to the input XML file as a parameter on the command line***

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie;

use XML::Twig;

use constant CHUNK_SIZE => 2;

my ( $xml_file ) = @ARGV or die "No input XML file specified";

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots               => { 'pmlcore:Observation' => \&handle_obs },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 0,
    pretty_print             => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile( $xml_file );

# Print any remaining chunks
print_chunk() if $twig->root->has_child( 'pmlcore:Observation' );

sub handle_obs {
    my ( $twig, $elem ) = @_;

    my $n = $twig->root->children_count( 'pmlcore:Observation' );
    print_chunk() if $n >= CHUNK_SIZE;
}

my $n;

sub print_chunk {

    my $filename = sprintf 'Name%d.txt', ++$n;

    open my $fh, '>', $filename;
    $twig->print( $fh );
    close $fh;

    say qq{"$filename" written};

    $_->delete for $twig->root->children( 'pmlcore:Observation' );
}
```

#### output

#### Name1.txt

```
<pmlcore:Sensor xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1" xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd">
  <paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name1</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number1</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name2</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number2</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
</pmlcore:Sensor>
```

#### Name2.txt

```
<pmlcore:Sensor xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1" xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd">
  <paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name3</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number3</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name4</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number4</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
</pmlcore:Sensor>
```

#### Name3.txt

```
<pmlcore:Sensor xmlns:pmlcore="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1" xmlns:pmluid="urn:autoid:specification:universal:Identifier:xml:schema:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:autoid:specification:interchange:PMLCore:xml:schema:1 ./PML/SchemaFiles/Interchange/PMLCore.xsd">
  <paraid:ID>1234</paraid:ID>
  <pmlcore:Observation>
    <childtag>Name5</childtag>
    <childtag2>Number5</childtag2>
    <childtag3>
      <childtag4></childtag4>
    </childtag3>
  </pmlcore:Observation>
</pmlcore:Sensor>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question though, what happens when the chunk size is larger, say 15? in that case if the remaining chunk after processing in groups of 15 is, say 9, would this make any change to the script?

Comment: No, that's fine. The line `print_chunk() if $twig->root->has_child( 'pmlcore:Observation' )` checks to see whether there are any `pmlcore:Observation` elements (there must be between zero and `CHUNK_SIZE-1` and prints another chunk file containing all the "spare" elements.

Comment: Ok, not working for me yet. Here's the comand line input and the subsequent errors i've run into:    
comand line - **./Perlsplit3.pl Perl_inputxml2.txt**
`./Perlsplit3.pl: use:  not found.`
`./Perlsplit3.pl[2]: use:  not found.`
`./Perlsplit3.pl[3]: use:  not found.`
`./Perlsplit3.pl[4]: use:  not found.`
`./Perlsplit3.pl[6]: use:  not found.`
`./Perlsplit3.pl[8]: use:  not found.`
`./Perlsplit3.pl[10]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 10 : `(' is not expected.`

Comment: @Kaladin: You're executing it as a bash script. Try `perl Perlsplit3.pl Perl_inputxml2.txt`